# Qualtrics: How to record which version of dynamic text was displayed to participant?

Tags: javascript, database, embed, qualtrics

**I am dynamically creating a table describing two hypothetical programs that I want participants to choose from:**
[image]

**To accomplish this, I have used java code that pulls from a list of opritons (for example, gender: men, women, trans-men, trans-women):**

[image]

**I use html to display the randomly selected word in the table:**

[image]

**And it successfully fills the table with text to participants.**
[image]

**I have added the variables to my survey flow:**
[image]

**However, when I look in the dataset, the columns are empty (i.e., it does not record the version of the randomized word that was displayed to participants!

Any help would be much appreciated**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `random*` column in the dataset is empty, because you are not storing anything over there.
The `setEmbeddedData` uses the following format `("Embedded Data Name", "Embedded Data Value")`. So instead of creating `my_word1` in your survey flow, create the embedded variable `word1`, because that is what you are storing.

The values already exists in your database, so you should be able to see these for previous responses also.